# Самый простой способ создавать облака

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Облака очень часто используются и в виде иконок и как отдельный элемент фона, фоновой анимации и во многих других случаях оформления веб страниц

Ниже пример одной из "облачных" иконок

```html
<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="350" height="350" viewBox="0 0 150 150"   >
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M104.1,52.9c0.1-0.8,0.1-1.5,0.1-2.3c0-16.9-13.7-30.6-30.6-30.6c-10.3,0-19.4,5.1-25,12.9
    c-1.7-0.4-3.5-0.6-5.3-0.6c-11.8,0-21.6,8.4-23.8,19.6c-4.7,0.9-8.9,3.3-12.2,6.5C2.8,62.8,0,68.9,0,75.7C0,89.1,10.9,100,24.3,100
    h71.5c13.4,0,24.3-10.9,24.3-24.3C120,65.3,113.4,56.4,104.1,52.9z M69.1,59.2c0,26.3,0,0,0,26.3c-10.7,0-2.9,0-15.5,0
    c0-26.3,0,0,0-26.3c-8.9,0,0,0-8.9,0c16.6-16.6,0,0,16.6-16.6c16.6,16.6,0,0,16.6,16.6C69.1,59.2,78,59.2,69.1,59.2z"/>
</svg>
```

**Возник вопрос**
Существует  ли простой способ менять конфигурацию контура облака ***без его перерисовки в векторном редакторе?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ не совсем имеет отношение к вопросу, поэтому ни на что не претендует. А просто по мотивам, на скорую руку, самый простой пример с использованием технологии `CSS` и лёгкой анимации.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.cloud,
.cloud>div:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: white;
  animation: 6s infinite linear ani0;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1):before,
.cloud>div:nth-child(1):after,
.cloud>div:nth-child(2):before,
.cloud>div:nth-child(2):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background: white;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1):before {
  right: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-85deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani1;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1):after {
  left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(85deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani2;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(2):before {
  right: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani3;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(2):after {
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani4;
}

@keyframes ani0 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  500% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-85deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-85deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(85deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(75deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(85deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani3 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}

.cloud>span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightskyblue;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px 0px rgba(30, 60, 80, 0.2) inset;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.cloud>span:before,
.cloud>span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: lightskyblue;
  background: radial-gradient(cornflowerblue, cornflowerblue 2px, lightskyblue 6px, lightskyblue 100%);
}

.cloud>span:before {
  left: -20px;
}

.cloud>span:after {
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud"><div></div><div></div><span></span></div>
```

К облачку добавим солнышко, чтобы на душе всем нам стало светлее и теплее =)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightskyblue;
}


/*Облако*/

.cloud {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1),
.cloud>div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: white;
  animation: 6s infinite linear ani0;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1):before,
.cloud>div:nth-child(1):after,
.cloud>div:nth-child(2):before,
.cloud>div:nth-child(2):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background: white;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1):before {
  right: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-85deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani1;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(1):after {
  left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(85deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani2;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(2):before {
  right: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani3;
}

.cloud>div:nth-child(2):after {
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation: 3s infinite linear ani4;
}

@keyframes ani0 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  500% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-85deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-85deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(85deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(75deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(85deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani3 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ani4 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}

.cloud>span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightskyblue;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px 0px rgba(30, 60, 80, 0.2) inset;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.cloud>span:before,
.cloud>span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: lightskyblue;
  background: radial-gradient(cornflowerblue, cornflowerblue 2px, lightskyblue 6px, lightskyblue 100%);
  animation: 6s infinite linear ani5;
}

.cloud>span:before {
  left: -20px;
}

.cloud>span:after {
  right: -20px;
}

@keyframes ani5 {
  2% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  4% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  6% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  8% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  10% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}


/*Солнце*/

.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 100px/100px 100px 100px 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
  animation: sun 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes sun {
  0% {
    border-radius: 100px/100px 100px 100px 100px;
  }
  2% {
    border-radius: 50px/50px 50px 100px 100px;
  }
  4% {
    border-radius: 100px/50px 50px 100px 100px;
  }
  6% {
    border-radius: 100px/100px 50px 100px 100px;
  }
  8% {
    border-radius: 100px/100px 100px 100px 100px;
  }
  10% {
    border-radius: 50px/50px 50px 100px 100px;
  }
  12% {
    border-radius: 100px/100px 100px 100px 100px;
  }
  18% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.sun>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 8px;
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: -41%;
  left: -2%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: -10%;
  left: -30%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 30%;
  left: -40%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 70%;
  left: -30%;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -41%;
  left: -2%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -41%;
  left: auto;
  right: -2%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -10%;
  left: auto;
  right: -30%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(10) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: auto;
  right: -40%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(11) {
  top: -41%;
  left: auto;
  right: -2%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.sun>div:nth-child(12) {
  top: -10%;
  right: -30%;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.sun>span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  width: 20px;
  height: 6px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid yellowgreen;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 4px 0px rgb(30 60 80 / 20%) inset;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, transparent 6px, red);
}

.sun>span:before,
.sun>span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: lightskyblue;
  background: radial-gradient(green, green 1px, yellowgreen 3px, yellowgreen 100%);
  animation: 30s infinite linear sun1;
}

@keyframes sun1 {
  13.5% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  13.8% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  14.1% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  14.4% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  14.7% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

.sun>span:before {
  left: -12px;
}

.sun>span:after {
  right: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud"><div></div><div></div><span></span></div>
<div class="sun"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><span></span></div>
```

Comment: Хороший, полезный ответ

Answer (score 7):

Техника решения создания разнообразных контуров облаков основывается на ответе:
**[Необычные эффекты stroke-dasharray](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255428/28748)**, где использовался прием с нулевой длиной черточки в атрибуте `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-linecap="round"`

Цель получить примерно такое облако:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Далее решение по шагам***

- Я закрасил stroke в чёрный цвет, чтобы были видны окружности по
  периметру эллипса.

```html
  



<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="dodgerblue" />
<ellipse  id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="black" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round"> 
</svg>
```

- Если `stroke="white"`, то белый фон эллипса сольется с белыми кругами
  и останется только внешний контур фигуры, который уже будет отдаленно
  напоминать облако:

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="dodgerblue" />
<ellipse  id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round"> 
</svg>
```

- Чтобы избавиться от этого однообразия краев облака, добавим второй
  эллипс с параметрами атрибутов, отличающимися от параметров первого
  эллипса.
- Для наглядности взаимодействия, окружности на двух разных эллипсах
  закрашены в разные цвета: зелёный и жёлтый

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1E589A" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8" />
     </linearGradient>
  </defs>
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
           <!-- Меньшие зелёные окружности размер задает stroke-width="70" -->
  <ellipse id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="green" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round"> 
         
    </ellipse>
             <!-- Большие жёлтые окружности размер задает stroke-width="100" -->
      <ellipse id="an_e2" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="gold" opacity="0.8" stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="0,100" stroke-linecap="round">
            
      </ellipse>        
 </svg>
```

- Теперь присваиваем всем `stroke="white"`
  Внутри контуров всё  сливается, остается более усложненная форма внешнего контура:

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1E589A" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8" />
     </linearGradient>
  </defs>
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
           <!-- Меньшие белые окружности, размер задает stroke-width="70" -->
  <ellipse id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round"> 
         
    </ellipse>
             <!-- Большие белые окружности, размер задает stroke-width="100" -->
      <ellipse id="an_e2" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" opacity="0.95" stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="0,100" stroke-linecap="round">
     </ellipse>        
</svg>
```

- Добавляем анимацию радиусов эллипсов, чтобы облака немного
  изменялись:

```
 <animate id="an_e1" attributeName="rx" begin="svg1.click" dur="30s" 
   values="200;250;200;200" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
   <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1E589A" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8" />
     </linearGradient>  
     <filter id="Shadow" x="-30%" y="-30%" width="200%" height="200%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" />
    <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" />
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.4"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  </defs>
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />  
   <g filter="url(#Shadow)">     
   <ellipse id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round" > 
         <animate id="an_e1" attributeName="rx" begin="svg1.click" dur="30s" values="200;250;200;200" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
    </ellipse>
    
      <ellipse id="an_e2" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="0,100" stroke-linecap="round">
            <animate attributeName="rx" begin="svg1.click" dur="20s" values="200;150;200;200" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </ellipse> 
   </g>       
    <text x="12" y="145" font-size="32px" fill="silver" >Click me </text> 
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Анимация облаков на растровой картинке

- Добавляем растровую картинку  внутрь svg

`<image opacity="1" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Ewi.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Весь код, который реализует облака, переносим в секцию `<defs>`
- Клонируем облака, попутно увеличивая, уменьшая клоны и попутно
  позиционируем их.  Всё это делается внутри тега `<use>` для каждой
  копии облака
- Добавляем команды анимации для перемещения облаков и уменьшения их
  прозрачности в конце пути.

*Анимация перемещения облаков начнется после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1280" height="720" viewBox="0 0 2560 1440">
   <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1E589A" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8" />
     </linearGradient>  
     <filter id="Shadow" x="-30%" y="-30%" width="200%" height="200%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" />
    <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" />
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.4"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  
     
   <g id="cloud" filter="url(#Shadow)">  
   <ellipse id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round" > 
   </ellipse>
    
      <ellipse id="an_e2" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="0,100" stroke-linecap="round">
      </ellipse> 
   </g> 
</defs>   
   <image opacity="1" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Ewi.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
      <g id="G1" opacity="1"> 
     <use x="650"  y="-250" href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.2 0.2)" />  
      <use href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.25 0.2)" /> 
        <use x="650"  y="250" href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.35 0.25)" />   
          <use x="200" y="300" href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.55 0.5)" />  
      <!-- Анимация перемещения облаков -->
      <animateTransform
       id="move"
       href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="translate"
       begin="svg1.click;op.end"
       dur="20s"
       values="
        0, 0;
        200,200;
        400,200;
        600,100;
        800, 0"
       repeatCount="1"
       additive="sum"   /> 
     
     <!-- Анимация прозрачности облаков -->
     <animate id="op"
       attributeName="opacity"
       begin="move.begin"
       dur="20s"
       to="0"
       additive="sum"
         />
   </g> 
</svg>
```

***Запуск и остановка анимации с того же места, где она была прервана***

Чтобы добиться повторного пуска анимации после её остановки можно использовать методы JS: `pauseAnimations()` и `unpauseAnimations()`

Добавлены две кнопки: остановки и запуска с событием onclick.

```js
let flag = 0,
    svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let start = function(){
  if(flag === 1){
    Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll('animateTransform')).forEach(e => e.removeAttribute('begin'));
    start = _ => svg.unpauseAnimations();
    start();
  }
  flag++;
}
const pause = function(){
  svg.pauseAnimations();
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1280" height="720" viewBox="0 0 2560 1440">
   <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1E589A" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8" />
     </linearGradient>  
     <filter id="Shadow" x="-30%" y="-30%" width="200%" height="200%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" />
    <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" />
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.4"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  
     
   <g id="cloud" filter="url(#Shadow)">  
   <ellipse id="el" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="70" stroke-dasharray="0,60" stroke-linecap="round" > 
   </ellipse>
    
      <ellipse id="an_e2" cx="300" cy="300" rx="200" ry="100" fill="#fff" stroke="white" stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="0,100" stroke-linecap="round">
      </ellipse> 
   </g> 
</defs>   
   <image opacity="1" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Ewi.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
      <g id="G1" opacity="1"> 
     <use x="650"  y="-250" href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.2 0.2)" />  
      <use href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.25 0.2)" /> 
        <use x="650"  y="250" href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.35 0.25)" />   
          <use x="200" y="300" href="#cloud" transform="scale(0.55 0.5)" />  
      <!-- Анимация перемещения облаков -->
      <animateTransform
       id="move"
       href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="translate"
       begin="gO1.click;move.end+1s"
       dur="30s"
       values="
        0, 0;
        200,200;
        400,200;
        600,100;
        700, 0"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
          /> 
     
     <!-- Анимация прозрачности облаков -->
     <animate id="op"
       attributeName="opacity"
       begin="gO1.click"
       dur="30s"
       to="0"
       additive="sum"
         /> 
   </g>     
          <!-- Блок управляющих кнопок -->
      <g transform="scale(2.4) translate(400,-50)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='start();'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g onclick='pause();'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```