# Как нарисовать 5 кругов на CSS на вершинах правильных многоугольников

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

Нужно нарисовать 5 одинаковых кругов, расположенных по кругу. Как я понимаю, нужна пятиконечная звезда, каждый угол которой будет центром круга. Я знаю как нарисовать звезду на CSS, но не понимаю, как взять координаты ее углов. Или может быть есть другой способ?

Comment: Добавлен [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1263803/28748)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно вручную, через CSS..

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.cir {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.cir > div {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(50% + 10px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(var(--r));
}

.cir > div:nth-child(1) {--r: 0deg;}
.cir > div:nth-child(2) {--r: 72deg;}
.cir > div:nth-child(3) {--r: 144deg;}
.cir > div:nth-child(4) {--r: 216deg;}
.cir > div:nth-child(5) {--r: 288deg;}

.cir > div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cir">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

*Пентаграмма - фигура с пятью вершинами, образованная двумя восходящими пересекающимися лучами, которые отходят от каждой стороны пентагона (правильного звездчатого пятиугольника), таким образом получается правильная пятиугольная звезда.*

Пускай еще в школе ваш покорный слуга и был лучшим по геометрии, и единственным, кто за всю историю школы сдавал экзамен по этому предмету и сдал его на твёрдую пятерку, а теперь извините, очень давно это было, всё уже позабыл - и термины, и формулы, и всё остальное. Поэтому мне сейчас проще взять из Интернета уже готовую с координатами картинку, и по ней работать. Например, такую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постараемся с помощью свойства `transform: rotate` вывести нужные нам точки каждой вершины:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png") 0% 0% no-repeat #eee;}

.container {
  position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container::after {content:""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 196px; height: 196px; border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 100%;}

.star div {
  position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 50%;
  border-radius: 8px; background: slategray;
  left: calc(50% - 4px); transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.s_1 {transform: rotate(0deg);}
.s_2 {transform: rotate(72deg);}
.s_3 {transform: rotate(-72deg);}
.s_4 {transform: rotate(144deg);}
.s_5 {transform: rotate(-144deg);}

.star div:before {
content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 8px; background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="star">
    <div class="s_1"></div>
    <div class="s_2"></div>
    <div class="s_3"></div>
    <div class="s_4"></div>
    <div class="s_5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или возьмем другую готовую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь у нас уже определены точные координатные оси, и нам будет проще абсолютным позиционированием с помощью свойства `position: absolute` распределить нужные точки.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png") 0% 0% no-repeat #eee;}

.container {position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;}

.star {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;}
.star::before {content:""; position: absolute; top: -85px; left: -85px; width: 170px; height: 170px; border: 1px solid orangered; border-radius: 100%;}

.star div {position: absolute; width: 11px; height: 11px; border-radius: 11px; background: red;}
.s_1 {top: -90px; left: -5px;}
.s_2 {top: -32px; left: -86px;}
.s_3 {top: -33px; right: -87px;}
.s_4 {bottom: -74px; left: -56px;}
.s_5 {bottom: -74px; right: -57px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="star">
    <div class="s_1"></div>
    <div class="s_2"></div>
    <div class="s_3"></div>
    <div class="s_4"></div>
    <div class="s_5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**В ответе использую фон координатной сетки, выполненный собственноручно участником @UModeL.**</sub>

Comment: Круто! Очень технологичное решение! Только в моей задаче круги должны быть большими и касаться друг друга. Но по данному принципу я уже смогу справиться

Comment: Хороший вариант. Особенно за реализацию "выставления" по координатной плоскости) (+)

Answer (score 3):

Ответ основан на сочетании атрибутов `stroke-linecap="round"` и `stroke-dasharray="0,N"`
подробнее здесь - **[Необычные эффекты stroke-dasharray](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255427/28748)**

При использовании данной  техники, - получения кругов на вершинах правильных многоугольников, можно легко решить задачу, не высчитывая координаты кругов. Даже знание SVG не требуется, нужную цифру для подстановки в `stroke-dasharray` выведет `console.log`

Необходимо только найти подходящий `path` и решить сколько круглых точек понадобится.

#1. Для звезды - нужно 5 кругов

Подставляем значение **16.86** из консоли в  `stroke-dasharray:0,16.86;`

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
}
#back {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0.5;
}
#p1 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:4;
stroke-dasharray:0,16.86;
stroke-dashoffset:8.43;
stroke-lineCap:round;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg   viewBox="-8 -8.5 40 43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  > 
<path id="back" fill="none" stroke="black"  d="M15.7 8.6l8.3 1.2-6.1 5.9 1.5 8.3-7.4-4-7.4 4 1.5-8.3-6.1-5.9 8.3-1.2 3.7-7.6 3.7 7.6zm-6.7l-6.8 5 4.8-1.2 6.8 6.1-3.3 6.1 3.3-1.2-6.8 5-4.8-6.8-0.9-3-6.2-3 6.2z"/>
<path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="black"  d="M15.7 8.6l8.3 1.2-6.1 5.9 1.5 8.3-7.4-4-7.4 4 1.5-8.3-6.1-5.9 8.3-1.2 3.7-7.6 3.7 7.6zm-6.7l-6.8 5 4.8-1.2 6.8 6.1-3.3 6.1 3.3-1.2-6.8 5-4.8-6.8-0.9-3-6.2-3 6.2z"/>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength() / 5); 
</script>
```

Как комментировал **@artbur**

> Только в моей задаче круги должны быть большими и касаться друг друга

Чтобы выполнить данное условие, нужно увеличить просто `stroke-width`

#2. `stroke-width:15;`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
}
#back {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0.5;
}
#p1 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:15;
stroke-dasharray:0,16.86;
stroke-dashoffset:8.43;
stroke-lineCap:round;
}

</style>
<div class="container">
<svg   viewBox="-8 -8.5 40 43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  > 
<path id="back" fill="none" stroke="black"  d="M15.7 8.6l8.3 1.2-6.1 5.9 1.5 8.3-7.4-4-7.4 4 1.5-8.3-6.1-5.9 8.3-1.2 3.7-7.6 3.7 7.6zm-6.7l-6.8 5 4.8-1.2 6.8 6.1-3.3 6.1 3.3-1.2-6.8 5-4.8-6.8-0.9-3-6.2-3 6.2z"/>
<path id="p1" fill="none" stroke="black"  d="M15.7 8.6l8.3 1.2-6.1 5.9 1.5 8.3-7.4-4-7.4 4 1.5-8.3-6.1-5.9 8.3-1.2 3.7-7.6 3.7 7.6zm-6.7l-6.8 5 4.8-1.2 6.8 6.1-3.3 6.1 3.3-1.2-6.8 5-4.8-6.8-0.9-3-6.2-3 6.2z"/>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength() / 5); 
</script>
```

### Примеры для шестиугольника

#2.1 Круги не касаются друг друга

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
#back {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
}
#p1 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:8;
stroke-dasharray:0,31.64;
stroke-lineCap:round;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="-18 -17 100 100" >
   <!-- Background hexagon -->
   <path id="back"  d="M48.9 60.9 16.9 60.9 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z"/>
      <!-- Six red dots -->
  <path id="p1"  d="M48.9 60.9 16.9 60.9 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z"/>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength() / 6); 
</script>
```

**#2.2 Круги касаются друг друга**

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
#back {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
}
#p1 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:32;
stroke-dasharray:0,31.64;
stroke-lineCap:round;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="-18 -17 100 100" >
   <!-- Background hexagon -->
   <path id="back"  d="M48.9 60.9 16.9 60.9 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z"/>
      <!-- Six red dots -->
  <path id="p1"  d="M48.9 60.9 16.9 60.9 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z"/>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength() / 6); 
</script>
```

### Примеры для восьмиугольника

#3.1 Круги отдельно

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
#back {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
}
#p1 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:40;
stroke-dasharray:0,169.8;
stroke-lineCap:round;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="-10 -10 420 420"  >
   <!-- Star-8 background -->
   <path id="back"  d="M305.1 94.9 268.6 171.6 348.6 200 268.6 228.4 305.1 305.1 228.4 268.6 200 348.6 171.6 268.6 94.9 305.1 131.4 228.4 51.4 200 131.4 171.6 94.9 94.9 171.6 131.4 200 51.4 228.4 131.4Z"/>
      <!-- 8 red dots -->
   <path id="p1"  d="M305.1 94.9 268.6 171.6 348.6 200 268.6 228.4 305.1 305.1 228.4 268.6 200 348.6 171.6 268.6 94.9 305.1 131.4 228.4 51.4 200 131.4 171.6 94.9 94.9 171.6 131.4 200 51.4 228.4 131.4Z"/> 
</svg>
</div>
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength() / 8); 
</script>
```

#3.2 Круги соприкасаются

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
#back {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:1;
}
#p1 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:115;
stroke-dasharray:0,169.8;
stroke-lineCap:round;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="-10 -10 420 420" >
   <!-- Star-8 background -->
   <path id="back"  d="M305.1 94.9 268.6 171.6 348.6 200 268.6 228.4 305.1 305.1 228.4 268.6 200 348.6 171.6 268.6 94.9 305.1 131.4 228.4 51.4 200 131.4 171.6 94.9 94.9 171.6 131.4 200 51.4 228.4 131.4Z"/>
      <!-- 8 red dots -->
   <path id="p1"  d="M305.1 94.9 268.6 171.6 348.6 200 268.6 228.4 305.1 305.1 228.4 268.6 200 348.6 171.6 268.6 94.9 305.1 131.4 228.4 51.4 200 131.4 171.6 94.9 94.9 171.6 131.4 200 51.4 228.4 131.4Z"/> 
</svg>
</div>
<script>
console.log(p1.getTotalLength() / 8); 
</script>
```