# Как изменть стартовую offset-position?

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация, css-animation

Анимация svg нужно анимировать несколько элементов, которые двигаються конвеером.

Как изменить начальную позицию любого элемента, чтоб он стартовал не с начала пути, а, например, по середине и потом возвращался в начало.

Вот так должна начинаться анимация.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут пример https://jsfiddle.net/v0L3u7s8/

```css
#road {
  stroke: #A7B1F9;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.item1 {
  stroke: #A7B1F9;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
  offset-path: path('M1277.5,38.5L924.6,901.2c-17.7,57.4-79,67.9-116.6,51.6l-770.7-315');
  offset-distance: 0%;
  animation: item1 10s linear 0.44s infinite;
}

.item2 {
  stroke: #A7B1F9;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
  offset-path: path('M1277.5,38.5L924.6,901.2c-17.7,57.4-79,67.9-116.6,51.6l-770.7-315');
  offset-distance: 20%;
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item2 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes item1 {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes item2 {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" />
    <clipPath id="road-clip">
      <use xlink:href="#road" />
    </clipPath>
    <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey" d="M1277.5,38.5L924.6,901.2c-17.7,57.4-79,67.9-116.6,51.6l-770.7-315" />
    <g clip-path="url(#road-clip)">
      <circle class="item1" r="90" />
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(#road-clip)">
      <path class="item2" d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45
c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Там 2 элемента, просто одновременно стартуют (круг и полукруг). Добавил задержку анимации теперь наглядней.  без разницы можно и smil. Если быть точным, то полукруг должен размещаться сразу после круга и когда дойдет до конца, начать с начала пути.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Прикрепил картинку, как должна начинаться анимация. То есть все элементы должны изначально находиться на ней и двигаться словно по конвееру. С задержкой анимации хорошая идея но немножко не то

Comment: @Sevastopol' да, но я не знаю как сделать, чтоб они начально были на конвеере. И начинали свое движение с определенного места.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал не так как хотел, но вот конечная реализация. Много кода, но все же.

```css
#road {
  stroke: #A7B1F9;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.item {
  stroke: #A7B1F9;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.line-way {
  stroke-width: 60;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 106 200 88 315 87 204;
  animation: line-animation 30s linear reverse infinite;
  stroke: #A7B1F9;
}

.mask-way {
  stroke-width: 54;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 104.5 200.5 87.5 316.5 85.5 205.5;
  stroke: #fff;
  animation: line-animation 30s linear reverse infinite;
}

@keyframes line-animation {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
}

.item4 {
  offset-path: path('M1244.5,120.7L924.3,901.2c-23.6,57.6-79,67.9-116.6,51.6L37,637.8l-320.8-139.5c-32.1-14-32-59.5,0.1-73.4l1648.8-782.7c34-14.7,68.6,19.4,54.5,53.7L1244.5,120.7');
  rotate: auto;
  transform: rotate(-112deg);
  animation: item-move 30s linear infinite;
}

.item3 {
  offset-path: path('M1210,204.4L924.3,901.2c-23.6,57.6-79,67.9-116.6,51.6L37,637.8l-320.8-139.5c-32.1-14-32-59.5,0.1-73.4l1648.8-782.7c34-14.7,68.6,19.4,54.5,53.7L1210,204.4');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear infinite;
}

.item1 {
  offset-path: path('M1101.3,470L922.2,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L1101.3,470');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear infinite;
}

.item2 {
  offset-path: path('M1176.1,286.6L924.3,901.2c-23.6,57.6-79,67.9-116.6,51.6L37,637.8l-320.8-139.5c-32.1-14-32-59.5,0.1-73.4l1648.8-782.7c34-14.7,68.6,19.4,54.5,53.7L1176.1,286.6');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear infinite;
}

.item5 {
  offset-path: path('M1070.3,545.4l-146,355.8c-23.6,57.6-79,67.9-116.6,51.6L37,637.8l-320.8-139.5c-32.1-14-32-59.5,0.1-73.4l1648.8-782.7c34-14.7,68.6,19.4,54.5,53.7L1070.3,545.4');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
  fill: white;
}

.item6 {
  offset-path: path('M995.4,728.9l-71.1,172.3c-23.6,57.6-79,67.9-116.6,51.6L37,637.8l-320.8-139.5c-32.1-14-32-59.5,0.1-73.4l1648.8-782.7c34-14.7,68.6,19.4,54.5,53.7L995.4,728.9');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item7 {
  offset-path: path('M705,910.1l-985.3-403.9c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.7,906.2c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L705,910.1');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item8 {
  offset-path: path('M517.2,830.7l-797.4-324.6c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.7,906.2c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L517.2,830.7');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item9 {
  offset-path: path('M467.4,812.4l-747.6-306.2c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.7,906.2c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L467.4,812.4');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item10 {
  offset-path: path('M291.1,740.5l-571.3-234.4c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.7,906.2c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L291.1,740.5');
  rotate: auto;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item11 {
  offset-path: path('M206.1,706.1l-486.3-200c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.7,906.2c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L206.1,706.1');
  rotate: auto;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item12 {
  offset-path: path('M121.8,672.1l-402.1-165.9c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.7,906.2c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L121.8,672.1');
  rotate: auto;
  transform: rotate(-112deg);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item13 {
  offset-path: path('M37.4,637.9L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L37.4,637.9');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item14 {
  offset-path: path('M-143.6,563.4L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-143.6,563.4');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: white;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item15 {
  offset-path: path('M-125.4,349.8l1488.7-707.3c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L-125.4,349.8');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item16 {
  offset-path: path('M56.9,264.2l1306.3-621.7c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L56.9,264.2');
  rotate: auto;
  transform: rotate(67deg);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item17 {
  offset-path: path('M240.7,176.6l1122.5-534.1c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L240.7,176.6');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item18 {
  offset-path: path('M311.1,142.7l1052.1-500.3c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L311.1,142.7');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item19 {
  offset-path: path('M397.4,101.5l965.8-459c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L397.4,101.5');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item20 {
  offset-path: path('M571.6,18.7l791.6-376.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L571.6,18.7');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item21 {
  offset-path: path('M693.6-39.1l669.6-318.4c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L693.6-39.1');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item22 {
  offset-path: path('M781.7-80.9l581.5-276.6c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L781.7-80.9');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item23 {
  offset-path: path('M954.1-162.7l409.1-194.8c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L954.1-162.7');
  rotate: auto;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item24 {
  offset-path: path('M1050.6-208.6l312.6-148.9c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L1050.6-208.6');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item25 {
  offset-path: path('M1233.1-294.7l130.1-62.8c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3L1233.1-294.7');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item26 {
  offset-path: path('M1370.9-186L922.1,906.1c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L1370.9-186');
  rotate: auto;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.07);
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

.item27 {
  offset-path: path('M1328.1-81.5l-406,987.6c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L1328.1-81.5');
  rotate: auto;
  animation: item-move 30s linear normal forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes item-move {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Шар_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 1080;" xml:space="preserve">

    <path id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" />

    <clipPath id="road2">
      <use xlink:href="#road" />
    </clipPath>

    <g clip-path="url(#road2)" >
      <path class="line-way" d="M1006.5,702.2l-84.3,203.9c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L1006.5,702.2" pathLength="1000"/>
    
    <path class="mask-way" d="M1005.3,705.1l-83.1,201c-18.2,44.2-68.8,65.3-113,47.1L-280.8,506c-35.7-14.6-37.1-64.7-2.2-81.3l1646.2-782.2
    c34.2-16.2,70.4,18.1,56,53.1L1005.3,705.1z" pathLength="1000"/>
      <path class="item item25 "
        d="M0,90c-35.6,0.7-69.6-19.9-84.5-54.6c-19.6-45.7,1.6-98.6,47.3-118.2c10.9-4.7,22.2-7,33.4-7.3" />

      <path class="item item6"
        d="M0,90c-35.6,0.7-69.6-19.9-84.5-54.6c-19.6-45.7,1.6-98.6,47.3-118.2c10.9-4.7,22.2-7,33.4-7.3" />
      <path class="item item7 "
        d="M-2.8-90c35.6-0.7,69.6,19.9,84.5,54.6c19.6,45.7-1.6,98.6-47.3,118.2C23.5,87.4,12.2,89.8,1,90" />
      <path class="item item8"
        d="M0,90c-35.6,0.7-69.6-19.9-84.5-54.6c-19.6-45.7,1.6-98.6,47.3-118.2c10.9-4.7,22.2-7,33.4-7.3" />
      <circle class="item item9" r="90" />
      <path class="item item10 "
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />
      <path class="item item11"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />
      <path class="item item12" d="M-83.1-34.7c13.3-33.1,45-54.5,82.8-54.5c49.7,0,90,40.3,90,90c0,12-2,22.2-6.2,32.6 M-41.5-17.6l-41.6-17
    c-4.2,10.4-6.6,21.8-6.6,33.8c0,49.7,40.3,90,90,90c37.6,0,69.7-23,83.2-55.7L42.1,16.6C35.3,33.1,19,44.8,0,44.7
    c-24.9-0.1-45-20.4-44.9-45.4C-44.8-6.7-43.7-12.4-41.5-17.6z" />

      <path class="item item13"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <circle class="item item14" r="90" />

      <path class="item item16" d="M-83.1-34.7c13.3-33.1,45-54.5,82.8-54.5c49.7,0,90,40.3,90,90c0,12-2,22.2-6.2,32.6 M-41.5-17.6l-41.6-17
    c-4.2,10.4-6.6,21.8-6.6,33.8c0,49.7,40.3,90,90,90c37.6,0,69.7-23,83.2-55.7L42.1,16.6C35.3,33.1,19,44.8,0,44.7
    c-24.9-0.1-45-20.4-44.9-45.4C-44.8-6.7-43.7-12.4-41.5-17.6z" />

      <path class="item item17 "
        d="M0,90c-35.6,0.7-69.6-19.9-84.5-54.6c-19.6-45.7,1.6-98.6,47.3-118.2c10.9-4.7,22.2-7,33.4-7.3" />

      <path class="item item18"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <path class="item item19"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <circle class="item item20" r="90" />

      <path class="item item21 "
        d="M-2.8-90c35.6-0.7,69.6,19.9,84.5,54.6c19.6,45.7-1.6,98.6-47.3,118.2C23.5,87.4,12.2,89.8,1,90" />

      <path class="item item22"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <path class="item item23"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <circle class="item item24" r="90" />

      <path class="item item26 "
        d="M-2.8-90c35.6-0.7,69.6,19.9,84.5,54.6c19.6,45.7-1.6,98.6-47.3,118.2C23.5,87.4,12.2,89.8,1,90" />

      <path class="item item27"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <path class="item item1"
        d="M0,90c-35.6,0.7-69.6-19.9-84.5-54.6c-19.6-45.7,1.6-98.6,47.3-118.2c10.9-4.7,22.2-7,33.4-7.3" />

      <path class="item item4" d="M-83.1-34.7c13.3-33.1,45-54.5,82.8-54.5c49.7,0,90,40.3,90,90c0,12-2,22.2-6.2,32.6 M-41.5-17.6l-41.6-17
    c-4.2,10.4-6.6,21.8-6.6,33.8c0,49.7,40.3,90,90,90c37.6,0,69.7-23,83.2-55.7L42.1,16.6C35.3,33.1,19,44.8,0,44.7
    c-24.9-0.1-45-20.4-44.9-45.4C-44.8-6.7-43.7-12.4-41.5-17.6z" />

      <circle class="item item5" r="90" />

      <path class="item item2"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <path class="item item3"
        d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" />

      <path class="item item15"
        d="M-2.8-90c35.6-0.7,69.6,19.9,84.5,54.6c19.6,45.7-1.6,98.6-47.3,118.2C23.5,87.4,12.2,89.8,1,90" />
    </g>

  </svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="mPath" d="M1277.5,38.5L924.6,901.2c-17.7,57.4-79,67.9-116.6,51.6l-770.7-315" fill="none" />
    <path id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" fill="none" stroke="#A7B1F9" stroke-width="3" />
    <clipPath id="road-clip">
      <use xlink:href="#road" />
    </clipPath>
    <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey" d="M1277.5,38.5L924.6,901.2c-17.7,57.4-79,67.9-116.6,51.6l-770.7-315" />
    <g clip-path="url(#road-clip)">
      <circle id="item1" r="90" fill="none" stroke="#A7B1F9" stroke-width="3" />
<animateMotion id="ani1" href="#item1" dur="4s" begin="0s" fill="remove" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"><mpath xlink:href="#mPath"/></animateMotion>
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(#road-clip)">
      <path id="item2" d="M-0.8-90C34.7-90.3,68.5-69.3,83-34.5C102,11.4,80.2,64.1,34.3,83.1C23.1,87.8,11.6,90,0.2,90l-0.3-45
c5.7,0,11.5-1.1,17.1-3.4C40,32,50.9,5.7,41.4-17.2C34.2-34.7,17.2-45.2-0.6-45L-0.8-90z" fill="none" stroke="#A7B1F9" stroke-width="3" />
<animateMotion id="ani2" href="#item2" dur="4s" begin="0.4s" fill="remove" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto"><mpath xlink:href="#mPath"/></animateMotion>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

**@tasina009** [комментирует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275947/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-offset-position#)

> Прикрепил картинку, как должна начинаться анимация. То есть все
> элементы должны изначально находиться на ней и двигаться словно по
> конвейеру

В вопросе путь не замкнут и одновременно он должен быть изначально заполнен полностью.
Поэтому тут не подойдут обычные решения с командами анимации `<animate>` и
`<animateMotion>` - движение объектов вдоль пути, так как путь уже заполнен.
Кроме того, как уже комментировали **@Sevastopol'** можно анимировать только один объект.
Для анимации нескольких объектов нужно несколько команд анимаций, что усложняет код.

Предлагаю обдумать решение, основанное на технике, приведенной  в ответе: [**Необычные эффекты stroke-dasharray**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255428/28748)

Для этого нужно замкнуть путь движения элементов и часть пути, как-то спрятать, чтобы было видно движение элементов только по желобу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На рис. выше серый прямоугольник это видимая часть холста SVG.

Красная линия - это замкнутый путь (трасса) движения элементов.

Как известно, что находится за границами холста SVG, будет визуально обрезано, но path останется рабочим на всей длине пути.

***Таким образом элементы будут постоянно двигаться вдоль всего пути, но мы будем видеть движение их только по желобу.***

Вторую проблему - движение нескольких объектов с помощью одной команды анимации, можно решить с помощью комбинации атрибутов `stroke-lineCap ="round"`, нулевой длины штриха и длине пробела, равной ширине `stroke-width` path трассы `stroke-dasharray ="0 170"` подробнее [тут](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1979)

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
#road {
fill:none;
stroke:#d5d5d5;
stroke-width:4;
} 

#trace {
fill:none;
stroke:dodgerblue;
stroke-width:170;
stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-dashoffset:5290;
stroke-dasharray:0 170;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" > 
<path id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" /> 
    <!-- Трасса, которая преобразована в круги -->
<path id="trace" d="M1277.5 38.5 924.6 901.2c-17.7 57.4-79 67.9-116.6 51.6l-770.7-315-308.9-124.5 3.1-886.2 1714.7-3.2-93.3 229.8z" >
      <!-- Анимация трассы, которая преобразована в круги с помощью stroke-dasharray:0 170; -->
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="14s" values="5290;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>  
    <!-- Экранирующие уголки -->
<path d="M1.1 737.1 78.9 531.5-0.8 528.3Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
  <path d="M1177.3 0.7 1367.4 74.2 1367.4 0.4Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Варианты с разным количеством объектов движения

> Как изменить начальную позицию любого элемента, чтоб он стартовал не с
> начала пути, а, например, по середине и потом возвращался в начало.

- Используется свойство `stroke-dasharray`, у которого может быть
  сколько угодно пар:
  **штрих, пробел**
- Если указана одна пара, то весь path будет равномерно разбит на
  равные сегменты
- Если использовать несколько пар параметров `stroke-dasharray`, то
  становится возможным комбинировать количество и начальное положение
  объектов движения

**#1.  Несколько кругов, которые начинают движение с середины желоба**

Каждая пара `0,170` это круг `0, 4100` - остальная часть `path` преобразованная в пробел.

*Формула расчета:*

Вся длина path - `5290px`

`170 * 7 = 1190px` длина, которую занимают шарики

`5290 -1190 = 4100px`  - остаток длины

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
#road {
fill:none;
stroke:#d5d5d5;
stroke-width:4;
} 

#trace {
fill:none;
stroke:#d5d5d5;
stroke-width:170;
stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-dashoffset:5290;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" > 
<path id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" /> 
    <!-- Трасса, которая преобразована в круги -->
<path id="trace" stroke-dasharray="
     0, 170
     0, 170 
     0, 170
     0, 170
     0, 170
     0, 170
     0, 170
     0, 4100" 
     d="M1277.5 38.5 924.6 901.2c-17.7 57.4-79 67.9-116.6 51.6l-770.7-315-308.9-124.5 3.1-886.2 1714.7-3.2-93.3 229.8z" >
      <!-- Анимация трассы, которая преобразована в круги с помощью stroke-dasharray:0 170; -->
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="5290;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>  
    <!-- Экранирующие уголки -->
<path d="M1.1 737.1 78.9 531.5-0.8 528.3Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
  <path d="M1177.3 0.7 1367.4 74.2 1367.4 0.4Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

**#2. Разная форма объектов**

Делается с помощью комбинаций пар параметров штрих-пробел.
Если указать длину штриха неравную нулю, то получатся "сосисочные" объекты

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
#road {
fill:none;
stroke:#d5d5d5;
stroke-width:4;
} 

#trace {
fill:none;
stroke:#FFC456;
stroke-width:170;
stroke-linecap:round;
stroke-dashoffset:5290;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" > 
<path id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" /> 
    <!-- Трасса, которая преобразована в круги -->
<path id="trace" stroke-dasharray="
     148,170
      0, 400
      0, 170
      148, 170
      0,400
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0, 548
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0, 170
      548, 170 
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0, 170
      0,548" 
     d="M1277.5 38.5 924.6 901.2c-17.7 57.4-79 67.9-116.6 51.6l-770.7-315-308.9-124.5 3.1-886.2 1714.7-3.2-93.3 229.8z" >
      <!-- Анимация трассы, которая преобразована в круги с помощью stroke-dasharray:0 170; -->
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="14s" values="5290;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>  
    <!-- Экранирующие уголки -->
<path d="M1.1 737.1 78.9 531.5-0.8 528.3Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
  <path d="M1177.3 0.7 1367.4 74.2 1367.4 0.4Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

**#3. Вариант с двумя трассами path для движения элементов**

- У первой трассы `path id="trace1"`  `stroke-linecap` не указан, поэтому вместо кругов  будут прямоугольники (значение по умолчанию)
- У второй трассы `path id="trace2"`  `stroke-linecap="round"`, поэтому будут круги
- Дополнительно появляется анимация перекрытия элементов с соседних
  path

```html
<style>
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 1366 1080" style="border:1px solid" > 
<path fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="6" id="road" d="M70.1,553.3l769.7,313.4l353.5-860l167.8,65.1l-354.3,869.5c-31.6,75.1-118,138.7-231.7,96.7L4.9,721.1
L70.1,553.3z" /> 
    
       <!-- Первый path преобразованный в прямойгольные элементы -->
 <path id="trace1" stroke-width="170" stroke="skyblue" fill="none"  stroke-dashoffset="5290" stroke-dasharray="
      170,170 340 170 510, 170"  d="M1277.5 38.5 924.6 901.2c-17.7 57.4-79 67.9-116.6 51.6l-770.7-315-308.9-124.5 3.1-886.2 1714.7-3.2-93.3 229.8z" >
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="15s" values="4950;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>    
       <!-- Второй path преобразованный в круглые элементы -->
<path id="trace2" stroke-width="170" stroke="skyblue" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="5290" stroke-dasharray="0,170 0,170" 
      d="M1277.5 38.5 924.6 901.2c-17.7 57.4-79 67.9-116.6 51.6l-770.7-315-308.9-124.5 3.1-886.2 1714.7-3.2-93.3 229.8z" >
  <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="14s" values="2645;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>   
            <!-- Маскирующие треугольники в начале и конце желоба -->
<path d="M1.1 737.1 78.9 531.5-0.8 528.3Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3"/>
  <path d="M1177.3 0.7 1367.4 74.2 1367.4 0.4Z" fill="white" stroke="#d3d3d3""/>
</svg>
</div>
```