# Как сделать постепенное заполнение бордера по кругу

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, анимация

Есть изображение с точечной обводкой. Нужно, чтобы при наведении эта обводка постепенно меняла цвет. Долго думал, так ничего нормального и не смог придумать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?
[image: Как это должно выглядеть]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Кратко

1. С помощью `stroke-dasharray`и `stroke-linecap="round"` получаете первую окружность с красными кружками
2. Добавляете поверх первой окружности точно такую же окружность с серыми кружками.
3. Создаете маску состоящую из прямоугольника и третьей окружности.
4. Анимируете маску, которая  с помощью stroke-dashoffset` будет двигаться и прорезать серые кружки, показывая тем самым красные кружки.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
<defs>
    <mask id="mask"> 
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" /> 
         <circle transform="rotate(-91 75 75)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="black" 
                stroke-width="6"    stroke-dashoffset="314.15"    stroke-dasharray="314.15" >
              <!-- анимация вращения маски прорезающей серые кружки, показывая тем самым красные кружки -->       
              <animate   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseleave" 
                 dur="4s" values="314.15;0" fill="freeze" />
        </circle>
    </mask> 
</defs> 
      <!--  Внутренний серый фон, здесь можно расположить иконку -->
   <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="35" fill="#d3d3d3" fill-opacity="0.5" />
   
     <!--  окружность c красными кружками -->
 <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="orangered" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/>    
   <!-- окружность c серыми кружками-->
  <circle mask="url(#mask)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/> 
</svg>
```

### Более подробно

1.С помощью `stroke-dasharray`и `stroke-linecap="round"` получаете первую окружность с красными кружками
Для создания кружков используется эффект, описанный подробно в ответе: **[Необычные эффекты stroke-dasharray](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255427/28748)**

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
      <!--  окружность c красными кружками -->
 <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="orangered" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/> 
 </svg>
```

2. Добавляете поверх первой окружности точно такую же окружность с серыми кружками.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
      <!--  окружность c красными кружками -->
 <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="orangered" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/> 
     <!--  окружность с серыми кружками -->
 <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/> 
 </svg>
```

3-4  Создание и анимация маски

Одним из свойств маски является прорезание верхнего слоя, в нашем случае серых кружков, до нижнего слоя (красных кружков) при `fill="black"`
Подробнее здесь:
**[Практические примеры применения масок svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)**

Ниже код, показывающий анимацию движения маски при прорезании серых кружков

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150" style="border:1px solid">
<!-- <defs> -->
    <!-- <mask id="mask">  -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" /> 
         <circle transform="rotate(-91 75 75)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="black" 
                stroke-width="6"    stroke-dashoffset="314.15"    stroke-dasharray="314.15" >
              <!-- анимация вращения маски прорезающей серые кружки, показывая тем самым красные кружки -->       
              <animate   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseleave" 
                 dur="4s" values="314.15;0" fill="freeze" />
        </circle>
    <!-- </mask>  -->
<!-- </defs>  -->
     <circle mask="url(#mask)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/>  
</svg>
```

5. Остается добавить условие запуска и остановки всей анимации при наведении `begin="svg1.mouseover"` и убирания курсора:    `end="svg1.mouseleave"`

Добавлена простая SVG иконка в центр

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
<defs>
    <mask id="mask"> 
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" /> 
         <circle transform="rotate(-91 75 75)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="black" 
                stroke-width="6"    stroke-dashoffset="314.15"    stroke-dasharray="314.15" >
              <!-- анимация вращения маски прорезающей серые кружки, показывая тем самым красные кружки -->       
              <animate   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseleave" 
                 dur="4s" values="314.15;0" fill="freeze" />
        </circle>
    </mask> 
</defs> 
   
   <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="38" fill="#d3d3d3" fill-opacity="0.5" /> 
             <!-- Иконка -->
  <g transform="scale(0.5) translate(100,100)" fill="#F00" stroke="#3b5998" stroke-width="4" pointer-events="none">
    <path d="M28,6h44v16l-22,21l-22-21z" fill="#6d84b4"/>
    <path d="M28,95h44v-16l-22-21l-22,21z" fill="#6d84b4"/>
    <path d="M6,30v42h15l21-21l-21-21z" fill="#afbfde"/>
    <path d="M95,30v42h-15l-21-21l21-21z" fill="#afbfde"/>
  </g>
   
     <!--  окружность c красными кружками -->
 <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="orangered" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/>    
   <!-- окружность c серыми кружками-->
  <circle mask="url(#mask)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-dasharray="0, 15.7075" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"/>  
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Исключительно на правах эксперимента — попытка сделать совсем без SVG (Chrome 85+)

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}

.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle::before {
  border: dotted 6px #ededed;
}

.circle:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
  mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
  background-image: conic-gradient( #ed1a11 var(--angle), transparent 0);
  animation: progress 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  to {
    --angle: 360deg;
  }
}

@property --angle {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: конический градиент не работает же в файерфоксе ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Конический градиент работает в FF, но там пока нет поддержки [@property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property), чтобы можно было его анимировать.

Answer (score 1):

### Вариант CSS

Идея решения точно такая же как в варианте SVG:
Используются две окружности, расположенные друг над другом.
Верхняя окружность с серыми кружками прорезается анимированной маской, показывая нижний слой с цветными кружками.

Стили представления SVG и анимация маски перенесены в правила CSS

Добавлена анимация закраски иконки при наведении:

```css
#orange {
fill:none;
stroke:orangered;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-lineCap:round;
stroke-dasharray:0, 15.7075;
} 
#grey {
fill:none;
stroke:#d3d3d3;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-lineCap:round;
stroke-dasharray:0, 15.7075;
}
#circMask{
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:0, 15.7075;
stroke-dashoffset:314.15;
stroke-dasharray:314.15;

}
#svg1:hover  #circMask{
animation: moveMask 4s;
}
@keyframes moveMask {
0% {stroke-dashoffset: 314.15;}
100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
} 
.blue {
fill:#6d84b4;
}
lightBlue {
fill:#afbfde;
}
#svg1:hover .blue {
animation: fillIcon 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes fillIcon {
to {fill:crimson};
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
<defs>
    <mask id="mask"> 
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" /> 
         <circle id="circMask" transform ="rotate(-90, 75, 75)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50"/>
    </mask> 
</defs> 
   
   <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="38" fill="#d3d3d3" fill-opacity="0.5" /> 
             <!-- Иконка -->
  <g class="icon" transform="scale(0.5) translate(100,100)"  stroke="#3b5998" stroke-width="4" pointer-events="none">
    <path  class="blue" d="M28,6h44v16l-22,21l-22-21z" />
    <path   class="blue" d="M28,95h44v-16l-22-21l-22,21z" />
    <path class="lightBlue" d="M6,30v42h15l21-21l-21-21z" />
    <path class="lightBlue" d="M95,30v42h-15l-21-21l21-21z" />
  </g>
   
     <!--  окружность c красными кружками -->
 <circle id="orange" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" />    
   <!-- окружность c серыми кружками-->
  <circle id="grey" mask="url(#mask)" cx="75" cy="75" r="50" stroke-width="6" />  
 </svg>
```